# Magento SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 5 Out of memory (Needed 268435428 bytes) error on clicking on manage product option

Tags: magento

I got  `SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 5 Out of memory (Needed 268435428 bytes)` error on clicking on manage product option in Magento 1.7. Can anybody guide what can be possible solution. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like your server doesn't have enough memory to run php and MySQL at the same time.

While others here have mentioned increasing the php memory_limit in php.ini, you've got a deeper problem as MySQL is running out of memory, not php:

Note the **error source is MySQL** --> `SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 5 Out of memory (Needed 268435428 bytes)`

You **are not** getting the standard php stack overflow --> `Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 247463936) (tried to allocate 261900 bytes) in somepath/to/some/file.php`

Server is inadequate for the demand or severly misconfigured on this one. You need more memory to run the whole ecommerce site. Expect data loss when MySQL isn't being provided adequate resources.

Answer (score 0):

My worked with below configuration on my.ini file.

> key_buffer = 1600M
>
> max_allowed_packet = 64M
>
> sort_buffer_size = 512M
>
> net_buffer_length = 80K
>
> read_buffer_size = 256M